# How to get the modulus of two functions

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic

I might be overlooking something, because what I want to do is quite elementary.

I want the following term `Mod[2(1 + z), (1 + z)]` to evaluate to `0` as expected.

The problem is that when I evaluate `Mod[2(1 + z), (1 + z)]`, it returns the input. I tried putting it into a block and restricting `z` to `Reals`, but nothing changed.

Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: This shouldn't be 2 but 0, if anything. Try `Simplify[Mod[2 (1 + z), (1 + z)], Assumptions -> z \[Element] Reals]`

Comment: Thanks, it works, but why when I put the same assumption in a `Block` it doesn't?

Comment: Please amend your answer to show what you tried. I can't comment based on guesses about what you tried.

Comment: An assumption only affects functions that use the option `Assumptions`. `Mod` doesn't take assumptions so unless you used `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` within the `Block`, the assumptions would have no effect. `Block[{$Assumptions = Element[z, Reals]}, Mod[2 (1 + z), (1 + z)] // Simplify`

Comment: Why aren't you using `PolynomialMod[]`? `PolynomialMod[2 (1 + z), (1 + z)]`

Answer (score 3):

```
Factor[2 (1 + z), Modulus -> 1 + z]
(* 0  * )
Factor[2 (z + 2) (z + 3) + (z + 4), Modulus -> z + 2]
(*  2  *)
Factor[2 (z + 2) (z + 3) + (z + 4) (y + 3), Modulus -> z + 2]
( * 6 + 2 y  * )
```